# C# Sort array element in list by date

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, date

I have a list

```
List<string[]> myList = new List<string[]>();
```

that holds an array that I want to sort by date inside of the list.

```
string[] myArray = new string[3];
```

The date is saved in place 0 in the array.

```
myArray[0] = (Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine())).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

How is that possible, when my print code looks like this?

```
foreach (string[] element in myList) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", element[0], element[1], element[2]);
}
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Your `myList` contains your `myArray`? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: "date is saved in place 0" to me sounds like you need a list of `MyObject`

Comment: You do not show any effort yourself. This problem and your last question smell like homework. SO is not a do your homework service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`List.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) and `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
myList.Sort((arr1, arr2) => DateTime.ParseExact(arr1[0], "yyyy'/'MM'/'dd", null)
                 .CompareTo(DateTime.ParseExact(arr2[0], "yyyy'/'MM'/'dd", null)));
```

This presumes that all have a valid format, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing data from an arbitrary array of strings, you should construct an object that represents your data and then make your list a list of this class.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public string Param2  {get;set;}
    public string Param3  {get;set;}
}
List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>();
```

In which case the sorting becomes trivial

```
foreach (var element in myList.OrderBy(x => x.Date))
```